# Time Control Problems

Tags: simcity-2013

The Time Control doesn't do anything on one city, then the other city its fine, and
I have no idea how to fix this. I tried going back to the city that works and then back again and it **still doesn't work**. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I then went back to the other city, and now that is having the same problem.  This is on a public region that I am hosting.

Comment: I just rebooted simcity and it didnt sync my citys but they are still there?

Comment: Which platform are you playing SimCity on?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the game or rebooting your computer?